# Reimplemented resizeEvent() is not called

Tags: c++, qt

Please check the following implementation:

**BoardView.h**

```
#include <QGraphicsView>

class BoardView : public QGraphicsView
{
protected:
    void        resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event);

public:
    BoardView();
};
```

**BoardView.cpp**

```
BoardView::BoardView()
{
}

void BoardView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
    QGraphicsView::resizeEvent(event);

    double wd = width();
    double ht = height();
    double min_wh = min(wd, ht);

    qDebug() << min_wh;

    QTransform transform;
    transform.scale(min_wh / Options::getMainBoardMinSize(), min_wh / Options::getMainBoardMinSize());
    setTransform(transform);
}
```

The above two files are directly copied from an existing project, say P1. The purpose of this code is to handle `resizeEvent()` and scale the view according to widget size.

The problem is, this works exactly as it should in project P1. Everything is scaled as expected. But `resizeEvent()` is not called from the new project at all, when the view is resized by resizing main window, on which it is a widget.

The BoardView object does everything else as expected. It shows the scene. It captures and passes mouse events to the scene etc. Only the `resizeEvent()` is not called.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Qt Creator 2.0.1, Qt 4.7 32 bit on Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit.

Comment: Are you saying that the view is properly scaled, but the function `BoardView::resizeEvent`, that does the actual scaling, is not called? Do you scale it somewhere else?

Comment: @ak, the board is not scaled at all. `BoardView::resizeEvent() `is not being called. the `qDebug()` doesn't output anything. What i'm saying is that i'm using the exact same files in a completely different project where `BoardView::resizeEvent()` gets called and the board is scaled properly.

Comment: @Donotalo : do you have a small Qt project that would demonstrate the problem and which we could try ?

Comment: @Jérôme: how can i upload files?

Comment: @Donotalo : there are plenty of file sharing sites. For instance, [File Dropper](http://www.filedropper.com/). Then, add the link to your question.

Comment: @Jérôme: i thought SO provides funtionality to do that. however, after creating minimal code, `BoardView` works. i'll figure out what is missing. thanks.

Comment: @Donotalo : ok, let us know !

Comment: Here is my code, that works: in the debug output I can see "test" when the view is resized. I'm on Mac OS 10.6, gcc 4.2, Qt 4.7.0

http://pastebin.com/AtzrMs2R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why a `BoardView::resizeEvent()` is not called, yet the `QGraphicsView` was showing the `QGraphicsScene` correctly? The reason is a silly mistake, instead of

```
BoardView _board_view;
```

I wrote

```
QGraphicsView _board_view;
```

Sorry for posting such a silly question!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Are you missing some code here?
Or your class declaration is incorrect - you should change it to

```
class BoardView : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT
...
public:
    BoardView(QWidget* parent);
};
...
BoardView::BoardView(QWidget* parent):QGraphicsView(parent)
{
}
```

Sorry if this is omitted by you because of triviality, but I don't know your QT experience level. This might be why QT events works incorrectly with your class...

Comment: please note, the exact same copy of files work in a different project.

Comment: the fact that it works somewhere else does not mean the code is ok. In this answer there is a good point: in the original code the base class constructor is not called: `BoardView::BoardView() {}`, while it should be at least `BoardView::BoardView(): QGraphicsView() {}`. Q_OBJECT is not necessary, as it initializes the signals/slots/meta functionality

Comment: @ak: the default constructor will be called automatically for `QGraphicsView()`. shouldn't it?